# Passing a list of numbers to google chart

Tags: django-templates, google-visualization

I'm using the django-chart-tools[0] application for Django. The problem is with the chd option, it requires a list of numbers: i.e 1,4,1,4,3,2,2... but I have app.2 which is: [1,4,1,...]. Is there a simple way of solving this?.

```
{% chart %}

    http://chart.apis.google.com/chart

    ?chs=300x150

    &cht=ls

    &chco=FF0000

    &chd=t:{{ app.2 }} # app.2 is a list of numbers

    chm=B,EFEFEF,0,0,0

{% endchart %}
```

[0] http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-chart-tools

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the newbie question, this is what I was looking for:

```
&chd=t:{{ app.2|join:',' }}
```